# Try-except doesn't re-run the entire code inside a for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, try-except

I'm really new to Python and writing code, and this code doesn't seem to rerun through all the lines after it hits the exception. I want it to start again from the try function after it hits the exception. Among these 40 web elements that the code is running through, maybe like 4-5 do not have this element (id="tt_single_values_spent) and will giveNoSuchElementException. What I want is that once my code will hit the error, it will skip it and continue to gather the information. I am 100% sure the problem is with the code and not the site itself
.

```py
for i in range(40):
    try:
        act4 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('dd[id="tt_single_values_spent"]').get_attribute('innerText')
        time_log = re.sub('h', '', act4)
        if time_log != str("Not Specified"):
           total_time.append(float(time_log))
           print(act4)
        pyautogui.press("down", 1);time.sleep(0.5)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Not found')
```

```
My result:
1h
45h
4h
13h
1h
31.8h
34.2h
5h
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
Not found
```

Comment: Are you concerned because it only gives 15 results?

Comment: It looks like this is just failing and getting an exception repeatedly, are you sure this isn't working correctly?

Comment: There's no result if the "try" part doesn't fail and the "if" case isn't met.

Comment: It prints out like 35 more Not founds, didnt want to paste them all

Comment: Kindly provide input html data to analyse and expected output as well.

Comment: Specifically, it will probably print out "Not found" another 25 times. What were you expecting to happen?

Comment: You don't use i. Why not just loop until "Not found" and end there? Do you have some reason to think the output is incorrect? pseudocode: "while True: try stuff except break"

Comment: Among these 40 web elements that the code is running through, maybe like 4-5 do not have this element (id="tt_single_values_spent) and will giveNoSuchElementException. What I want is that once my code will hit the error, it will skip it and continue to gather the information.

Comment: Consider moving the "go to next" into a `finally` or outside the try catch...

Comment: @tehhowch thank you, the "finally" thing helped me

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code repeatedly outputs "Not found" once it encounters a single "Not found" element, is that your code only advances elements within the `try` block.

Instead, you should always advance. You can do this with a `finally` block, or with code outside of the try-except block:

```py
for i in range(40):
    try:
        act4 = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('dd[id="tt_single_values_spent"]').get_attribute('innerText')
        time_log = re.sub('h', '', act4)
        if time_log != str("Not Specified"):
           total_time.append(float(time_log))
        print(act4)
    except NoSuchElementException:
        print('Not found')
    finally:
        pyautogui.press("down", 1)
        time.sleep(0.5)
```